# SpringCloudGateway - routing issue with duplicate service name in URL

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to implement a `API-Gateway` service over our project using `Spring-Cloud-Gateway`.

Consider that I have a service named `admin` and I'm trying to configure it's route as below:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      routes:
        - id: admin_route
          uri: lb://admin
          predicates:
            - Path=/admin/**
```

It compiles successfully but there is just a problem!!

I have an API on `admin` service with a URL like below that works fine without a gateway:

```
http://localhost:<ADMIN_PORT>/admin/system/employee/check
```

But when I want to call this API through `gateway` service, I have to duplicate the `admin` in the URL, like below, so that it works fine:

```
http://localhost:<GATEWAY_PORT>/admin/admin/system/employee/check
```

Does anybody have any idea or clue how to resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated!!

**Note: Spring-Boot 2.7.0,
Soring-Cloud 2021.0.3,
Java 1.8**

******************** UPDATE ************************

I have set `servlet-context-path` and `apllication.name` in admin's `application.yml` as below:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: admin
server:
  port: <ADMIN_PORT>
  servlet:
    context-path: /admin
```

I think that it is the reason why I need to duplicate the service name in the URL, But I couldn't find any configuration on `SpringCloudGateway` related to this topic!!

******************** ATTENTION ************************

I am not allowed to remove `servlet-context-path` which has been set to `/admin` from admin's `application.yml`, because I need them to call my services internally without getting help from `Gateway`!!

So I need the following URL:

```
http://localhost:<GATEWAY_PORT>/admin/system/employee/check
```

to be routed to the following address:

```
http://localhost:<ADMIN_PORT>/admin/system/employee/check
```

without `/admin` getting removed after routing!!

Still, any help would be appreciated!!! :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the culprit is this config:

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
```

from [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__configuration.html#_discoveryclient_route_definition_locator):

> 8.2 DiscoveryClient Route Definition Locator The Gateway can be configured to create routes based on services registered with a
> DiscoveryClient compatible service registry.
>
> To enable this, set
> spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true and make sure a
> DiscoveryClient implementation is on the classpath and enabled (such
> as Netflix Eureka, Consul or Zookeeper).
>
> 8.2.1 Configuring Predicates and Filters For DiscoveryClient Routes By default the Gateway defines a single predicate and filter for routes
> created via a DiscoveryClient.
>
> The default predicate is a path predicate defined with the pattern
> /serviceId/**, where serviceId is the id of the service from the
> DiscoveryClient.
>
> The default filter is rewrite path filter with the regex
> /serviceId/(?.*) and the replacement /${remaining}. This
> just strips the service id from the path before the request is sent
> downstream.

so when you call the following URL:

```
http://localhost:<GATEWAY_PORT>/admin/system/employee/check
```

the gateway rewrite the path to `/system/employee/check`, because `admin` is the service name.

when you call :

```
http://localhost:<GATEWAY_PORT>/admin/admin/system/employee/check
```

the gateway rewrite the path to `/admin/system/employee/check`, which is the correct one.

Comment: That's a nice solution! After info provided in my answer I was thinking about manual configuration of PathRewrite, but didn't know there's a config flag just for that.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should alter the name of your admin service in both the `pom.xml` and `application.yml` files. Consider choosing a name like `admin-service` or something distinct from the name `admin`.

After you have made this change, you should update the service name in the gateway to match the new name you have chosen for the admin service. By doing so, you will ensure that the predicate and service uri are distinct from one another.

Once you have made these changes, your gateway should be able to successfully route requests.

###### admin service application.yml:

```yaml
    spring:
      application:
        name: admin-service
```

###### gateway service application.yml:

```yaml
    spring:
      application:
        name: gateway
      cloud:
        gateway:
          discovery:
            locator:
              enabled: true
              lower-case-service-id: true
          routes:
            - id: admin_route
            uri: lb://admin-service
            predicates:
              - Path=/admin/**
```

Comment: Wow, you really saved me!!! it works fine, but "pom.xml" does not need to be changed in <name> tag as it is only used for maven to load the project.
changing "aplication.name" in application.yml is enough and works fine!!
Thanks for your help and complete answer

Answer (score 1):

The API gateway does a match on url prefix in this case `admin` and then redirects call to specified service which does a match on remaining url. `SpringCloudGateway` is unaware of internal routing of your service. You could replace `context-path: /admin` with `context-path: /tomato` and then you'd need to inlcude `tomato` in url.

Solution would be to drop the `admin` prefix on the implementing service configuration. From what you've described it's intended to be used via API Gateway anyway, so service mappings without `admin` wouldn't be accessible anyway to consumers. Since default value is `/` just remove property `servlet.context-path` from `application.yaml`

As per Eureka discovery your service reports its name via following
properties (excerpt from documentation)

> The default application name
> (that is, the service ID), virtual host, and non-secure port (taken
> from the Environment) are ${spring.application.name},
> ${spring.application.name} and ${server.port}, respectively.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html

Comment: I can not remove "servlet.context-path" property as I need it to call my services APIs internally, And I don't want my gateway route my internal service calls!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the route URI configuration.

You have this:

```
uri: lb://admin
```

chenge it to this:

```
uri: lb://
```

Comment: that's my service name and is used to communicate with Eureka and can not be deleted!!!   Even the code won't get compiled successfully with lb://